# Prestashop translation not showing up

Tags: smarty, translation, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I just created a new module to manage some strings. I installed the module and i see the texts on the backend to translate.
So far, so good.
But the problem is, that once i translate and save, i can't seem to get the updated information on the frontend.

I added this into my product.tpl template

```
{l s='CI' mod='aproductimages'}
```

That translation, according to Prestashop, is saved as "http://.......image.jpg", but when i print it on the template, i only get "CI" (the original string, not the translation)
I tried downloading my module's translation files, but they're empty.
Is that correct? am i missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have simliar problem with the difference is that, i am displaying template by creating new smarty object and then fetch template data. In this template, i have used translation variable like "{l s='varname' mod='mymodule'}". Now i am getting the error for unknow tag "l" in smarty template. You can also check the same with explanation on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990153/unknown-tag-l-in-smarty-prestashop?noredirect=1#comment51903552_31990153]. If you have any idea what is the prob with this, please share your solution with me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very often in Prestashop You need to flush page and browser cache memory.

In Prestashop BO go to ***Advanced Parameters / Performance*** and turn cache off and force theme compilation. Then use ***Clean Smarty and Autoload cache*** button.

Next clean browser and refresh Your site by CTRL+F5.

This should help!

Comment: Thanks for you answer!, i tried your approach but i'm missing the Clean Smarty and Autoload cache button, there's nothing in the performance page to do this.
Is there any other way around it?, should my module translation files be updated automatically?

Comment: If Your PS dont have this button http://nemops.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/clear_smarty_cache-680x343.png then You need to delete all content from compile/smarty/CACHE folder . You can do this safetly. Nothing will happend to Your site

Comment: Thanks, gotta try that!!

Comment: Sadly that didn't work either, i cleared all caches, but translations are still not showing up :(

Comment: " I tried downloading my module's translation files, but they're empty." - check this file permissions too.

{l s='CI' mod='aproductimages'} in product.tpl? Use rather {l s='CI'} and translate apropriate string in BO

Comment: @MichaelKäfer Did your find a solution?

Comment: @JonnyDevv which PS version?

Comment: @PrestaShark I'm in version 1.7.5. It's working now. Add to change to new translations system using syntax {l s='Text to translate' mod='mymodule'}. Now I'm having troubles to translate form errors in my new module form in front office. $this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->l('error message') doesn't appear in backoffice translation system.